# Is it possible to load in facetracker and blink after nth amount of seconds in SPARK AR?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I haven't found an answer to this yet, the docs don't really provide much info as well.

But is it possible to load in blink detection after nth amount of seconds?

For example, after 5 seconds, blink detection loads and and starts sending signals to my script.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the blink action for the first 5 seconds. Here's how you'd do it with patches: [screenshot of blink detection after 5 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qDmS.png)

The way it works is, the "runtime" patch and "greater than" patches trigger if the runtime is greater than 5. That is is connected to an "and" patch, along with the blink detection and you're effectively ignoring blinks before 5 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the Time module, you can call scripts on a timer.

```
const Time = require('Time');

function onTimeout(){
    //do stuff after 5 seconds
}

let delay = 5000; //5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
Time.setTimeout(onTimeout, delay);
```

Documentation of the Time module can be found here: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/developer/reference/classes/TimeModule